# How to auto increment a non primary id column using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, increment

I have kept auto increment for primary key, by using auto increment option in my Table. 
And I stated that using hibernate.

But now I want to auto increment a column which is not a primary key column using Hibernate Annotation.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @user2345416 did you find answer to this question. Please let me know I am running into this issue but still cant seem to find a solution even in the era of hibernate 4.x

Answer (score 1):

Use the following annotation over the specific field

@GeneratedType

private int non_Primary_field