# Is it possible to autoincrement a column which is not primary key

Tags: android, database, primary-key, android-sqlite, auto-increment

I have two columns `Index` and `path`. Because of present logic of my code I want path to be `primary` key and also Index to be `auto Increment`. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible. How u are connecting to database? See for hibernate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350938/how-to-auto-increment-a-non-primary-id-column-using-hibernate

Comment: @MadhavC there is no ans

Comment: @MadhavC I want in context with android

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by making `path` `primary key`? Quite likely there's a better way to do that without needing to "change complete logic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GUID value is intended to be unique across tables and even databases so, make the auto_increment column primary index and make a UNIQUE index for the GUID. I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you eventually want that `path` will be auto-incremented,
I've done so with the use of trigger upon new value, Run these two commands in your table creation process

```
        String sqlTableCreation = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER primary key, " +
            "%s integer DEFAULT 0)",
            Contract.TABLE,
            Contract.INDEX,
            Contract.PATH
            );

    String sqlPathAutoIncrement = 
            String.format("CREATE TRIGGER pk AFTER INSERT ON %1$s" +
                    " BEGIN" +
                    "     UPDATE  %1$s" +
                    "     SET     %2$s = 1+ (SELECT MAX(%2$s) FROM %1$s) " + 
                    "     WHERE   ROWID = new.ROWID;" + 
                    " END;" , 
                    Contract.TABLE,
                    Contract.PATH,
                    Contract.INDEX);
```